# Android while(true) внутри Thread не работает

Tags: android, многопоточность, while

Пытаюсь выводить на экран пользователя сообщение в новом фоновом потоке через  Toast.makeText, если выводить один раз вне цикла - все получается, но когда пытаюсь сделать это в цикле while (true) - черный экран. В чем проблема?

```
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
       while(true) {
                h.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Сообщение", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                });
                 }
                 }
                 });
```

Comment: Наверное в том, что Вы непрерывно забиваете очередь этими раннаблями и не оставляете системе времени, чтобы обработать хотя бы один. Сделайте хоть какую-то передышку - с такой частотой юзер всё равно не успеет увидеть сообщение, как оно уже сменится другим.

Comment: Как сделать задержку?

Comment: Например, [`Thread.sleep(milis)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)). Но я бы не советовал вообще использовать бесконечный цикл без крайней необходимости. Многие задачи можно решить другими способами.

Comment: Мне вообще нужно слушать ответ сервера через сокеты, но почему-то у меня не работает. Я задавал вопрос здесь, в отдельной теме но к сожалению никто не отозвался. Вот я и ищу проблему в мелочах, на данный момент безрезультатно.